# SourceGear merge of .sqlproj files

Tags: sqlproj, sourcegear-vault

We use Sourcegear Vault Standard version 8.0.1 (299) with VS2013. The .sqlproj file extension has been added to the inclusion list and now when doing a merge Vault wants to overwrite the project file. As a general rule I think that is a bad idea. With the extension not in the inclusion list Vault does nothing with the project file.

What is the proper configuration to get Vault to merge VS2013 SQL project files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default Vault isn't set to merge project files.  You can change that by adding the project file extension to the mergeable files list.  Go to the Vault admin web page, expand the repository list on the left, and click on the repository name.  Then look to the right and scroll down.  There you will see a list of file extensions in the mergeable file list.  Just add your extension and save.

If you have further questions about Vault, you can feel free to ask at their public forum at support.sourcegear.com.